# Twig 2 - Incorrect value from 2 number_format

Tags: php, twig

I'm seeing some odd behaviour from twig 2 trying to use number_format.

I get 3 values from my server for each item: cost, multiplier and quantity.  Because of the multiplier I was getting partial cents when multiplying by the quantity, so I put price in a variable like so:

```
{% set price = (item.buyPrice * item.markup_mult)|number_format(2) %}
```

That's fine, I use it on the next line and it's correct.  The problem is when I try to use the price value in another variable with a second formatting:

```
{% set lineTotal = (price * quantities[item.collection_id][item.item_id])|number_format(2) %}
```

Like this, I will get the value of 2.00, because my lineTotal SHOULD have been 2400 something.

3 Things to note:

1. This only occurs if the price is over $1000, otherwise it's fine. This doesn't happen if the price is under $1000 but when multiplying the quantity, the total is over $1000 - I feel like this can't be a coincidence.  Something to do with the number of digits maybe?
2. I have it in a variable as a test, I had originally had it in line but also I get the error message:  "$
   Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\Apache24\htdocs\tekinventory.dev\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(372) : eval()'d code on line 198
   2.00 "
   as well as the value 2.00
3. If I take the "|number_format(2)" off of the set price line, everything works fine, except that I then occasionally get rounding errors in the final price (the original problem)

I've also read the

Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number_format` outputs a string, meaning you're trusting automatic type conversions.  When you use `number_format` by default it automatically inserts a thousands-delimiter (in the U.S., a comma).  That's probably messing up your math and explains why it's only a problem for prices above $999.99.

Rather than using `number_format`, you need to use `round()`.

```
$number = 1000.999
echo number_format($number,2); // 1,001.00
echo round($number,2); // 1001

$number = 1000.99
echo number_format($number,2); // 1,000.99
echo round($number,2); // 1000.99
```

Comment: Ah this does work if I use round on the initial price, and then number_format for the actual output on the price and totals lines. 

I didn't think to actually look at the number_format in PHP docs, because I thought Twig would have changed or added enough behaviour to make them too different.  Thanks!